# Function to draw a polygon from a scatterplot with nested array data

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts

I have a dataset which are the result of a clusteranalysis. These points are displayed in a scatterplot. I need to draw a polygon around the values, but when I use the values of the cluster, I get a wrong polygon. This is my dataset which draws the scatterplot and the polygon in the graphic below.

```
[
    [
      0.875136458459595,
      -0.0839615159119212
    ],
    [
      0.979761664449852,
      0.357190949561656
    ],
    [
      0.871451278090475,
      0.341407867545605
    ],
    [
      0.448043398260893,
      -0.704849536235642
    ],
    [
      0.532598868920512,
      -0.326410807317216
    ],
    [
      0.980210441328016,
      0.25160846416046
    ],
    [
      0.0806967770808654,
      0.0897156451770012
    ]
```

[image]

To draw the polygon correctly, I need to sort the values, since the first points connects with the second and so on. Points which are inside the polygon shall be ignored totally. This is the desired result and how it looks like.

```
[
    [
      0.979761664449852,
      0.357190949561656
    ],
    [
      0.980210441328016,
      0.25160846416046
    ],
    [
      0.875136458459595,
      -0.0839615159119212
    ],
    [
      0.448043398260893,
      -0.704849536235642
    ],
    [
      0.0806967770808654,
      0.0897156451770012
    ],
    [
      0.871451278090475,
      0.341407867545605
    ],
]
```

[image]

I tried to sort the arrays by their first values but this did not give me the desired result, since the points still overlap. Does anyone have an idea how to tackle this problem?

Comment: Just like in the answer - sorting points is not enough - https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sL84ovcz/ it is easy to see that for the polygon series the points should be in different order to achieve wanted format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertex set is already by definition a polygon. Sorting points will not help you. What you need is running [a Convex Hull algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms) on those points data set. There are many Javascript implementations of convex hull, take [this lib](http://brian3kb.github.io/graham_scan_js/) or [this from GitHub](https://github.com/AndriiHeonia/hull) and apply to your vertex set.